# ¿Por qué este for loop genera un bucle infinito?

Tags: javascript, bucle-for

Tengo dos `array` de 2 dimensiones:

```
var curInv = [
    [21, "Bowling Ball"],
    [2, "Dirty Sock"],
    [1, "Hair Pin"],
    [5, "Microphone"]
];

var newInv = [
    [2, "Hair Pin"],
    [3, "Half-Eaten Apple"],
    [67, "Bowling Ball"],
    [7, "Toothpaste"]
];
```

Y hago una función para que los items en `newInv` que no estén en `curInv` se añadan a este último:

```
function updateInventory(arr1, arr2) {

    for (let i=0; i<arr2.length;i++){
      for (let j=0; j<arr1.length;j++){
        if (arr2[i][1] === arr1[j][1]){
          arr1.push(arr2[i])
        }
      }
    }

    return arr1;
}

//LLamo a la función con esos dos array como argumentos, y me devuelve un bucle infinito aparentemente:

updateInventory(curInv, newInv); // se congela la consola
```

Lo que me llama la atención aún más es que si simplemente modifico esto:

```
arr1.push(arr2[i])
```

por esto:

```
arr1.push(arr2[i][1])
```

Entonces la consola no se congela ya. Pero de esa manera no me envía el `array` completo, sino sólo el item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estás editando `arr1` mientras lo recorres. Mejor crea un nuevo array sobre el que operar:

```js
var curInv = [
    [21, "Bowling Ball"],
    [2, "Dirty Sock"],
    [1, "Hair Pin"],
    [5, "Microphone"]
];

var newInv = [
    [2, "Hair Pin"],
    [3, "Half-Eaten Apple"],
    [67, "Bowling Ball"],
    [7, "Toothpaste"]
];

function updateInventory(arr1, arr2) {
    var nuevoArray = Array.from(arr1);
    
    for (let i=0; i<arr2.length;i++){
      for (let j=0; j<arr1.length;j++){
        if (arr2[i][1] === arr1[j][1]){
          nuevoArray.push(arr2[i])
        }
      }
    }
    
    return nuevoArray;
}

console.log(updateInventory(curInv, newInv));
```